# Calculating table columns with decimal numbers using jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are ton of solution in Stackoverflow to calculate the totals of a column. That part I already solved. The issue is that of a total of 13 columns, only two are actually decimal numbers.This table get the data using ajax/datatables jQuery plugin (I don't know if the info is necessary but just in case).

[image]

If you look at the columns, the correct calculation should be 3113.27, but it rounds the number to 3111, so it is not taking into consideration the decimals.This is the code I'm using.

```
$("#example tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
var t = 0;
$(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
    t += parseInt($(this).text(), 10 || 0);
});
return t;
});
```

Again, the rest of the columns are fine, because I just need to count/sum, but these two are causeing me trouble. Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you post your html structure

Comment: I'm just throwing this out there, but do you think it could have something to do with the parseInt, and `10 || 0`, what do you think that returns ?

Comment: Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: I already tried parseFloat() before, but the issue is that then I get a really long number: 3113.2700000000004. I need to limit it to two decimals.Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aLgx6/1/

Comment: Thanks adeneo, I tried your suggestion combined with Daniel's and it work perfectly:                                              `$("#example tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    return parseInt(t * 100, 10) / 100;;
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt()` returns an integer (i.e. no decimals). If you use `parseFloat()` it should work fine.

Comment: I already tried parseFloat() before, but the issue is that then I get a really long number: 3113.2700000000004. I need to limit it to two decimals.Thanks!

Comment: In that case you can do ` parseFloat( $(this).text().toFixed(2)  );` the `toFixed()` takes a single argument that is the number of decimal places you want to return. However, you have to make sure that you `parseFloat()` the result. If you don't, toFixed() will return a string.

Comment: @DanielBernhard, `toFixed` is a Number method, `jQuery(x).text()` returns a String.

Comment: @JoelCornett good point. I guess to do this you would need to do `parseFloat( parseFloat( $(this).text  ).toFixed(2)   )`. @cubanGuy please advise.

Comment: This worked perfectly: `$("#example tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){     var t = 0;     $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){         t += parseFloat($(this).text());     });     return parseInt(t * 100, 10) / 100;; });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#example tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i) {
  var t = 0;
  $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
    t += parseFloat(this.innerText) || 0;
  });

  return t.toFixed(2);
});
```